# Do stats actually matter in Venetica?

Tags: venetica

I've been playing Venetica recently. Your character has 4 attributes:

1. Constitution
2. Wisdom
3. Strength
4. Mental Power

When I increase constitution it increases my health. When I increase Wisdom it increases my mana. But when I increase my other stats I don't see any changes on the screen. Do the other stats even matter a damn? I've been increasing my constitution and strenghth all along and am not sure whether the stats are actually having any effect on my attacks. Any idea what the other stats do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual.

Strength: More damage with your weapons

Mental Power: More damage with your spells